# Ran a wrong command using Wine

Tags: apt, wine, directory

I tried to recognize what version of Wine I had installed, but itstead of

```
wine --version
```

I ran

```
wine version
```

As I understood it tried to run application with the name "Version", which doesn't exist on my system. Here is the output:

```
frowyy@LenovoV510-15IKB:~$ wine version
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/frowyy/.wine'
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
wine: configuration in L"/home/frowyy/.wine" has been updated.
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\version.exe" not found
```

It was my first time opening a program using Wine and that's why, as I understood, some directories were created. But I mostly wonder about these errors in the output: What do they mean? Is everything fine? Will Wine work correctly? Do I need to reinstall it?

Comment: I do not see in the supplied info any mention of making directories.

Comment: ```wine: created the configuration directory '/home/frowyy/.wine'``` I mean this. Yeah, it's not an created directory, but configuration file. But I wonder about these errors: Is everything is okay?

Comment: I do not see anything you need to fix or remove so I would say it is fine.

Comment: Okay, but please could you explain what do the errors with "MarshallInterface" and "local_server_stream" mean?

Comment: It is trying to find the program which you know does not exist as you made a typo. I do know more about wine then that.

Comment: Okay, thanks in advance! I just always kind of scared of something going wrong and then cause some problems, but as I understood I don't have to do anything and everything should be fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trying to find the program which you know does not exist as you made a typo. I do know more about wine then that.